# Import problems in Python-based git submodules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a hypothetical project A:

**Project_A**

```
-> __init__.py
-> source
--> package_a
---> __init__.py
---> module_a.py
--> package_b
---> __init__.py
---> module_b.py
-> tests
--> __init__.py
--> tests.py
-> Runner.py
```

module_b.py imports a class_a from module_a via relative import:

**module_b.py**

```
from ..package_a.module_a import class_a
```

That works well for me, as long as I operate within this project on its own. Moreover, I have recently moved to an **absolute imports style**, and it still works fine, as long as I remember to add Project A's **root folder to path in **init**.py in root folder**:

**root folder **init**.py**

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname, abspath
sys.path.append(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
```

While this approach works fine within Project A's scope, it starts to give me problems, when I attempt to treat Project A as a dependency of Project B, via *git submodule* mechanism:

**Project_B**

```
-> __init__.py
-> source
--> package_c
---> __init__.py
---> module_c.py
-> tests
--> __init__.py
--> tests.py
-> Runner.py
-> .gitmodules
-> thirdparty
--> Project_A (Subproject commit ...)
```

If I try to call class_a from Project_A's package_a, from Project_B's module_c, I do get **ImportError** if Project_A uses absolute imports style.

I do realise it is caused by Python's interpretter looking for e.g. package_a.module_a.class_a, while in Project_B's scope, and it does not find package_a in it, nor in OS's PATH.

Is there any elegant way of dealing with that problem? Somehow, putting path.append() logic in every **init**.py in the whole project feels wrong, since its is far from a DRY approach.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your problem but I don't think it has anything to do with git.  Python doesn't know about the fact that you're in a git repository and doesn't care.

Comment: It has too do with the fact, that when Project_B's logic tries to use Project_A, Python's interpreter does not know where to look for package_a.module_a, since it is not a part of pip-installed packages, it is in the root folder of Project_B, and path to it is not in PATH environmental variable. It would help, if Git added it to PATH at the time of import as a submodule, but I don`t think Git should be taking care of something like that.

Comment: You don't mean PATH, you mean PYTHONPATH (places Python looks for imports) or `sys.path`. But you're right that Git won't do anything about any of these: Git is not relevant here.

Comment: As long as both packages are in a path that's on your `sys.path`. If both are in your current working directory they will be by default. Otherwise you can add that directory to your PYTHONPATH, or ideally make a basic `setup.cfg` and run `pip install -e .` to link the path of your source tree to the standard import path

Comment: Does git take care of running the pip install -e command? It feels like when git pulls submodules, it should look for a setup.cfg or setup.py in their root dir, and run it to properly install them.